# How to migrate IdMappedPortTCP indy 9 to indy 10

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe, indy

I have code in delphi with a component indy 9 IdMappedPortTCP in Event OnExecute...
but when I implemented in indy 10,I have an error

Code Event OnExecute component indy 9 IdMappedPortTCP :

```
procedure TForm1.IdMappedPortTCP1Execute(AThread: TIdMappedPortThread);
if (pos('CONNECT',athread.NetData)<>0) or (pos('GET',athread.NetData)<>0) or (pos('POST',athread.NetData)<>0) then
begin
Athread.NetData :=Athread.NetData+'GET http://www.rianekacahya.net/ HTTP/1.1'#13#10+'Connection: Keep-Alive'#13#10+'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0'#13#10+'Host: '#13#10#13#10#13#10+Athread.NetData;
end;
```

event OnExecute,not the equal between indy 9 and indy 10

Indy 9 :

```
procedure TForm1.IdMappedPortTCP1Execute(AThread: TIdMappedPortThread);

end;
```

Indy 10 :

```
procedure TForm1.IdMappedPortTCP1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);

end;
```

How to migrating my code to indy 10 ?

Comment: In Indy 10, you can access `NetData` via `TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).NetData`, however the type has changed from `string` to `TIdBytes`.

Comment: This code looks like you are manually implementing an HTTP proxy server.  Indy 10 has a `TIdHTTPProxyServer` component for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

use TIdMappedPortTCP class (in IdMappedPortTCP.pas) for Indy10.
forget TMyMappedPortTCP.

;)